# Selecting only records from one table that exist in another table

Tags: php, scope, relationship, octobercms

I am using October CMS to build a website for a restaurant and I'm working on the menu page.

I have two tables "Sections" and "Menu Items". Sections can have many Menu Items, but Menu Items can only have one section.

I'm wanting to create a scope so that if there is a Section that does not contain any Menu Items, it will not be returned. That way I don't have any empty headers on my page when they are displayed.

I have my relationship already setup.

**SECTIONS MODEL**

```
public $hasMany = [

    'menuitems' => ['elnorteno2\restaurantmenu\Models\MenuItem', 'key' => 'section_id']

];
```

**MENU ITEMS MODEL**

```
public $belongsTo = [

    'section' => 'elnorteno2\restaurantmenu\Models\Section'

];
```

I just don't know what to put Sections model for the scope definition.

```
public function scopeSections($query)
{
     ??????
}
```

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to google the right thing.

I would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want only such data that exist in 2 table with same key or id?

then yes you can do it by using join query. let me give you example that i have used before.

### EXAMPLE

table_A have
id name email password

table_B have 
id user_id order_no total

query

```
SELECT table_A.id, table_A.name FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.id = table_B.user_id;
```

Happy coding...

Comment: But what would the actual code that goes under the scopeSections function?

Comment: can you show me of structure structure of both table with some randome data so that i will provide you query after testing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this

```
public function scopeSections($query)
{
    return $query->has('menuitems');
}
```

> may be better name `scopeHavingSubmenu`

if any doubt please comment